# MySQL if string contains ' symbol how to search in LIKE

Tags: mysql

How can I search name from database if my string contains `'` symbol?

This is my query that I am trying to search, but I am unable to search like this.

```
SELECT  * from  distributor where name  like'%jeni'%'
```

How to search text if my string contains `'` symbol?

Answer (score 3):

You should escape it (like in pretty much every situation like this)

```
SELECT  * from  distributor where name  like'%jeni\'%'
```

You can also find more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: but how can i find it

Comment: @GaneshGudghe what do you mean?

Comment: how can i add \ before '

Comment: @GaneshGudghe: that's not clear. How? By hand perhaps? It depends but should not big a big deal. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Double up the single quote.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM distributor 
WHERE name LIKE '%jeni''%'
```